# Magento 2 - jsError - Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined

Tags: magento2, javascript

In every pages of my custom template on the console log I find this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined

the error come's from:

> Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup.js at line 25

I haven't modify this file and never used it, what's the problem?

Comment: please deploy run command and check again

Comment: I've already tryed, but nothing change

Comment: you have to first delete pub/static folder and run command again

Comment: Yes I did also that, but nothing

Comment: great comments, guys. this is an actual bug because I'm experiencing it as well. For me, it happens inside an iframe where I removed the header & footer from the layout, so its obviously happening because I no longer have a login action or checkout autocomplete function in the header.

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right, I also change the header and the footer, that's the problem

Comment: We're also experiencing this issue. Our header and footer are present on the checkout pages we are currently seeing the issue on, so I don't think this issue has to do with you removing them, and I've ran across several tickets describing this exact error, but the suggested solutions didn't have any impact for us.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8532 < For anybody else who comes across these threads, it is apparently a known issue that is being tracked and appears to be fixed in the 2.2 release.